# check if quantity overlaps using addbetweencondition in yii

Tags: php, yii

looking to not insert when the quantity is within range.. not sure what im doing wrong.. it keeps inserting. Column, from, and to, what am i missing?

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->addBetweenCondition('add_min_qty', $this->add_min_qty,'add_max_qty');
$criteria->addBetweenCondition('add_max_qty','add_min_qty',$this->add_max_qty);
```